# jQuery click function to trigger bootstrap menu slide down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to trigger bootstrap navbar dropdown menu slide down by clicking on the dropdown link. It does work when hovering over the dropdown link by using jQuery's hover function:

An example fiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/sykk7dwv/16/

Here is the relevant HTML code:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
   <div class="container">        
       <div class="navbar-header pull-left">     
         <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
       </div>    
       <div class="navbar-header-menu">
         <ul class="nav navbar-nav centered-navbar">                 
           <li class="dropdown mega-dropdown active">
             <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> Link1 <span class="caret"></span>
             </a>    
             <ul class="dropdown-menu mega-dropdown-menu">
               <div class="SomeContent">
                 &nbsp Link1
                 <br>
                 &nbsp Link2
                 <br>
                 &nbsp Link3
                 <br>
               </div>
             </ul>
           </li>
         </ul>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.navbar {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.25);
}
.mega-dropdown {
  position: static !important;
  padding-left: 30px;
}
.mega-dropdown-menu {
    padding: 0px 0px !important;
    width: 100% !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none !important;
}
.mega-dropdown-menu > li > ul {
  padding: 0 !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
}
.mega-dropdown-menu > li > ul > li {
  list-style: none !important;
}
.mega-dropdown-menu > li > ul > li > a {
  display: block !important;
  color: #222 !important;
  padding: 3px 5px !important;
}
.mega-dropdown-menu .dropdown-header {
  font-size: 18px !important;
  color: #ff3546 !important;
  padding: 5px 60px 5px 5px !important;
  line-height: 30px !important;
}
.navbar-collapse.collapse {
  display: block!important;
}
.navbar-nav>li, .navbar-nav {
  float: left !important;
}
.navbar-header-menu {
  float: left;
}
.navbar-header-menu > .navbar-nav {
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
} 
.navbar-header-menu > .navbar-nav > li {
  float: left;
}     
.navbar-header-menu > .navbar-nav > li > a {
   padding-top: 15px;
   padding-bottom: 15px;
}
.navbar-header-menu > .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu {
   position: absolute;
   float: left;
   width: auto;
   margin-top: 0;
   background-color: #fff;
   border: 1px solid #ccc;
   border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.15);
   -webkit-box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0,0,0,.175);
   box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0,0,0,.175);
}  
.navbar-header-menu > .navbar-form {
   float: left;
   width: auto;
   padding-top: 0;
   padding-bottom: 0;
   margin-right: 0;
   margin-left: 0;
   border: 0;
   -webkit-box-shadow: none;
   box-shadow: none;
}
.navbar-header-menu > .navbar-form > .form-group {
   display: inline-block;
   margin-bottom: 0;
   vertical-align: middle;
}
.navbar-header-menu > .navbar-left {
   float: left;
}  
.navbar-header-menu > .navbar-right {
   float: right !important;
}
.navbar-header-menu > *.navbar-right:last-child {
   margin-right: -15px !important;
}
```

And this is the jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".dropdown").hover(            
        function() {
            $('.dropdown-menu', this).not('.in .dropdown-menu').stop(true,true).slideDown("400");
            $(this).toggleClass('open');        
        },
        function() {
            $('.dropdown-menu', this).not('.in .dropdown-menu').stop(true,true).slideUp("400");
            $(this).toggleClass('open');       
        }
    );
});
```

However, when I replace jQuery's "hover" by "click" function

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".dropdown").click(            
        function() {
            $('.dropdown-menu', this).not('.in .dropdown-menu').stop(true,true).slideDown("400");
            $(this).toggleClass('open');        
        },
        function() {
            $('.dropdown-menu', this).not('.in .dropdown-menu').stop(true,true).slideUp("400");
            $(this).toggleClass('open');       
        }
    );
});
```

, the dropdown menu does not open. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you please provide the `CSS` for the relevant `HTML` elements? I would like to see what properties you are using to hide/show the menu. Thank you. Also if you include the relevant `CSS` a more accurate snippet can be used in your question.

Comment: Just included the relevant CSS.

Comment: I still cannot get this to function with **JsFiddle** Maybe something is missing? If you could provide a working example that would be much easier to work with. Thank you. [**My JsFiddle Assemble Attempt**](https://jsfiddle.net/pzcwv2cf/)

Comment: I am working on it.

Comment: May be invalid syntax? Click only takes 1 handler it seems: https://api.jquery.com/click/ while hoer has 2 handlers `.hover( handlerIn, handlerOut )`

Comment: @Rikin: Good hint - when I remove the second part of the function (the subfunction with the slideUp part) the dropdown menu does slide down on click, but obviously does not close anymore...

Comment: Yep so you just need to modify your handler to toggle to meet your desired rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated the answer with the fiddle

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".dropdown").click(            
        function() {
            $('.dropdown-menu', this).not('.in .dropdown-menu').stop(true,true).slideToggle("400");
            $(this).toggleClass('open');        
        }
    );
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pzcwv2cf/1/

Comment: Just tried it, this does not solve it. Dropdown menu does not open.

Comment: @schustischuster fixed it check it now